# Mobile vs. desktop branding: They look like different sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, mobile-web

I use Stack Overflow on the desktop when coding, but in the evenings I use the mobile version. I noticed the branding doesn't match between these and at first glance they look like different sites / brands.

Here are a couple of screenshots:

[image: Mobile vs. desktop branding]

Mobile is blue; desktop is black and orange. Maybe you will consider adjusting these in a future update?

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/

Comment: I agree, consistency throughout entrypoints for each SE site is important.

Comment: I agree, mobile experience (browser and native) is so much different (and poor) from the main site that the site identity is totally lost.

Comment: It's nice having one app and a unified experience for the different SE sites. But a dash of colour would help to understand what site I'm browsing right now.

Comment: The top links navbar (Questions, Tags, Users, etc.) in the app could easily be themed with the site's colors, without losing the Stack Exchange branding. Alternatively, the site's logo and logotype could be used at the very top.

Comment: I think this question should be migrated to Meta.SE, since it's not only SO-related.

Comment: This question will be looks weird on meta.SE, since SE already had blue theme

Comment: I usually use the full site on my mobile devices... because the mobile site sucks, plain and simple.

Comment: This is annoying enough that I turn my phone sideways and put firefox in "PC site mode" so that I can see what I'm used to -- and not get a completely crippled interface. Its not just a *different* interface, its a totally crap interface.

Comment: @zxq9 The mobile interface is *mostly* fine; I use it all the time. There are some completely bogus "features" like [the unusable close-as-duplicate dialog](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171199/237313) though. (I presume this hasn't been fixed; I haven't actually tried lately.)

Comment: @TinyGiant Don't use the mobile site, install the app instead. The app is great.

Comment: @Kieran There are like 150 different SE sites. We'd need 150 different dashes of color. It's way harder to have 150 different mobile app designs (within a single app) than 150 different websites layouts. I'd rather have a single unified experience within the app.

Comment: @Thiago, if it isn't the full site, I don't want it.

Comment: @TinyGiant You should try it. It works great for trivial tasks such as reading this question, upvoting some comments and adding a couple of new ones :)

Comment: @Thiago The vast majority of my activity on this site is moderation activity. If the app is lacking any of the features of the full site, it isn't worth my time.

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula Just what I want -- to install another app on several mobile devices so that I can almost do what I can already do through the web interface. While native applications are *critical* for deep functionality, typing and tapping "up/down" isn't exactly deep... and I'm still not sure why the app needs access to my device storage (not that I'm suspicious of SE, I just don't know why it would need that). That mobile ff works the same as the desktop ff is a huge relief.

Comment: @Tiny Isn't that a shame, though? I mean, I hear you, and I am exactly the same way. But it is entirely unfortunate that most of our time is spent engaging in moderation activity, rather than what we *should* be spending our time doing: learning new things by reading answers, sharing our knowledge by answering questions, etc.

Comment: @CodyGray At least I'd like to think lots of people enjoy moderating more than me (and maybe you). For me reading great Q/As is my favorite part of SO, but I end up rage-moderating quite a bit every time I get near the front page.

Comment: @zxq9 Notifications.

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula Perhaps I am peculiar in this regard, but I want *fewer* things that cause noises, flashes, indicators, screen blinks, popups, etc. to come from my phone, not more. What I mostly want to do is read answers and maybe answer some questions. That's it. Just *browse* the site -- and that's not app-worthy, and its not very easy to do from the mobile site. That there is an app is nice -- its just not for me, that the site works well is great -- its the main face of the site; but the *mobile* site sucks in every way -- it causes problems instead of solves them.

Comment: This reminds me, actually... a lot of sites that have a "mobile site" *and* an app deliberately make their mobile site suck to encourage mobile users to install their app. I really hope this isn't (even subconsciously) the decision SE has taken. But it smells an awful lot like that tactic, and that stinks.

Comment: @CodyGray There are many parts to play in this game of knowledge. Some people primarily ask questions, others primarily answer questions, some even just read questions and answers, we spend most of our time attempting to keep the site clean for all of those other users. Take away any one group and the whole system would fail. Would I like there to be less crap to clean up so that I could spend more time enjoying the quality content on the site? Sure. Is that liable to happen? Not a chance in hell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've just slightly updated branding of our mobile skin for Stack Overflow. Other sites also have updated skin but it's unified across whole network for now. In simple words: only Stack Overflow got branded skin (at least for now). It's still not perfectly the same as desktop but in our opinion it is now more recognizable as Stack Overflow.